# EF4 : not persisted elements

Tags: entity-framework, code-first

I use EF4 code first to fill a tree to allow users to organize their reports into folders.
My model is not very simple because it is buit on an existing database.
I have 1 database table mapped to 2 classes in the model (Table Per Hierarchy) that inherit from another :

- Base class : Organization
- Inherited Class : Organization_Report
- Inherited class : Organization_Folder

A folder has a Children property that is a collection of Organization instances.
In the Organization class, i've got a NumParent member and a Navigation Property : Parent that points to the Parent Folder.

Top level elements have a NumParent = null.

I want Reports that don't have a parent (NumParent = null) to be groupped into a "virtual" (ie. not persisted) folder : "Not organized elements".

In other words, when querying the database, I have to create the "Not organized elements" folder and set Parent to it for every Report that has NumParent = Nothing.
When saving to the database, I want this folder not to be added.

Is that possible with EF ?

Comment: It is too vague question to be answered. It is not clear what your data model is and what do you want to do.

Comment: yes, you're right. I will try to be more precise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not related to EF - it is your application logic. EF is just tool which will load or persist data. If you need anything additional you will have to implement it yourselves. In this case you will probably need to implement handler for `ObjectContext.ObjectMaterialized` to assign dummy folder to loaded entities and override `ObjectContext.SaveChanges` or implement handler for `ObjectContext.SavingChanges` to remove that dummy folder prior to persisting changes - this will be tricky because you must fix the object tree and make sure that there is no reference to your dummy folder otherwise it will be persisted. It also means that after you persist changes your data will not contain that special folder.

If you use DbContext API you can still convert your context to ObjectContext and assign handlers.